# Getting quite frustrated learning JavaScript, want some advice

Tags: javascript

I joined a Front-End development Bootcamp in February, and covering HTML and CSS was pretty easy and I did pretty well with those when we moved on to javascript,we have been learning javascript,for a bout a month or 2, and I am still finding it quite challenging to implement, I understand some concepts, but I really struggle applying them, we have done 1 project, which was to build a to-do app, which I did really bad at, and a to-do app is one of the basics to build when learning JS.

So I took a step back and tried to build a calculator, which, I got the foundation down and had the values of the buttons display in the screen, so manipulating the DOM, I get and can do, but I had to come on stack overflow so many times on how to do something and its getting frustrating that I am not yet able to apply what I have learnt so far with javascript, for a simple calculator, which again is a simple thing to do in JS.

I make it a point to stay away from tutorials,as I do not want to be trapepd in tutorial hell.

Any advice someone can give, I know practicing is the only way, is this part of the journey or am I that dumb to get Javascript?

Comment: Don't get discouraged. I've been coding for 25 years and I still get frustrated sometimes, but I'm also always learning something new. You've been coding for _two months_. Don't beat yourself up over it. Just take it one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Andy, my goal is to become a front end developer and even though my html and css is pretty good, I am worried I wont be able to get a job as a front end developer if my javascript is bad

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not a matter of being "dumb" or "smart." Programming takes a certain step-by-step way of thinking. For some people, that way of thinking is second nature, the way they already think about things. Others tend to think more big picture and intuitive leap, and step-by-step is new and alien for them. Most people are somewhere in-between. But the step-by-step thing can be learned. I believe nearly anyone can learn programming, and JavaScript may have a couple of weirdnesses, but it's easier to learn than some other programming languages. I suspect if you keep at...

Comment: ...it, you'll have one of those "ah hah!" moments and things will suddenly start flowing much more easily. (The whole event-driven thing in the browser environment can be a bit alien as well.) As Andy says, we all feel like we're being "dumb" sometimes -- in my case, after programming for about 40 years, 30 of them professionally. While that isn't necessarily helpful in a practical way, hopefully it is in the "we're all in much the same boat" way. :-) Happy coding!